# How to remove div with a particular text in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some div tags which has some text & elements in it & I want to remove those div's, They are looks like this

```
<div style="font-family:verdana;font-size:12px;">
    Example
    <a href="http://www.example.com" title="hey">example</a>
</div>
```

There are many div's like this & I want to remove them all with using jQuery or javascript

Comment: Is there anything they have in common? The url they point. the inline style.. anything to make sure we can get **only** these undesired divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Darren's answer, if you want to be extra sure (as `:contains` will match and delete any div containing the word `example`), you can make sure it's a div that has an anchor with that same example as children, then go back to the parent and remove it.

If this doesn't work, please paste a few more divs so we can see a common pattern and target it the safest way possible.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('#remove').click(function(e){

  $("div:contains('Example')").children("a:contains('example')").parent("div:contains('Example')").remove()
})
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="font-family:verdana;font-size:12px;">Example<a href="http://www.example.com" title="hey"> example</a></div>
<div style="font-family:verdana;font-size:12px;">Don't remove<a href="http://www.example.com" title="hey"> example</a></div>
<div style="font-family:verdana;font-size:12px;">Example<a href="http://www.example.com" title="hey"> don't remove</a></div>

<button id="remove">
Remove undesired divs
</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

If the elements have nothing in common such as a class, you can remove it by using the [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method.

```
$("div:contains('Example')").remove()
```

Full example shown below:

```js
$("div:contains('Example')").remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  Example
</div>
<div>
  Darren
</div>
```

If the elements do have something in common you could use the class selector.

```
$(".common-class").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I'm writing it $('div:contains('example <a href="http://www.example.com" title="example">example</a>')').remove(); it is giving an error SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: It's not removing, i tried like this <script>
$('div:contains("example <a href="http://www.example.com" title="example">example</a>")').remove();
</script>